# How do I merge array of Objects but unshift array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I would like to merge these two array of objects but for `urls` I would like to use unshift to merge arrays instead of replacing.

Here's an example

```
var arr1 = [{
  "keyword": "name",
  "score": 0.8992112752974006,
  "urls": ["url1"],
  "ids": ["5748bf9ab58adb2f614da195"]
}, {
  "keyword": "name1",
  "score": 0.39953909596222775,
  "urls": ["url2"],
  "ids": ["5743260055f979a31fa98971"]
}, {
  "keyword": "name3",
  "score": 0.4960953181766197,
  "urls": ["url4"],
  "ids": ["58c04cd5208b4945c3920cad"]
}, {
  "keyword": "name4",
  "score": 0.3337163443410707,
  "urls": ["url5"],
  "ids": ["573628c38e32eeb039377f7e"]
}];

var arr2 = [{
  "keyword": "name",
  "score": 0.8992112752974006,
  "urls": ["url6"],
  "ids": [""]
}, {
  "keyword": "name1",
  "score": 0.39953909596222775,
  "urls": ["url7"],
  "ids": [""]
}]
```

I would like the result to be

```
[{
  "keyword": "name",
  "score": 0.8992112752974006,
  "urls": ["url6", "url1"],
  "ids": ["5748bf9ab58adb2f614da195"]
}, {
  "keyword": "name1",
  "score": 0.39953909596222775,
  "urls": ["url7", "url2"],
  "ids": ["5743260055f979a31fa98971"]
}, {
  "keyword": "name3",
  "score": 0.4960953181766197,
  "urls": ["url4"],
  "ids": ["58c04cd5208b4945c3920cad"]
}, {
  "keyword": "name4",
  "score": 0.3337163443410707,
  "urls": ["url5"],
  "ids": ["573628c38e32eeb039377f7e"]
}];
```

Here's my attempt but the result would replace the array of urls;

```
var a3 = arr1.concat(arr2).reduce((acc, x) => {
  acc[x.keyword] = Object.assign(acc[x.keyword] || {}, x);
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(a3);
```

It would be just the `urls` that it will be merged. Other values will be overridden.

Comment: just for the urls?

Comment: Should other values be overridden?

Comment: Just for the urls, other array will be overridden.

Comment: [Overwritten](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88400/when-to-use-override-and-overwrite) since you are writing over the previous entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for collecting the objects with the same `keyword` and update if necessary. This solution works for an arbitrary count of arrays.

```js
var array1 = [{ keyword: "name", score: 0.8992112752974006, urls: ["url1"], ids: ["5748bf9ab58adb2f614da195"] }, { keyword: "name1", score: 0.39953909596222775, urls: ["url2"], ids: ["5743260055f979a31fa98971"] }, { keyword: "name3", score: 0.4960953181766197, urls: ["url4"], ids: ["58c04cd5208b4945c3920cad"] }, { keyword: "name4", score: 0.3337163443410707, urls: ["url5"], ids: ["573628c38e32eeb039377f7e"] }],
    array2 = [{ keyword: "name", score: 0.8992112752974006, urls: ["url6"], ids: [""] }, { keyword: "name1", score: 0.39953909596222775, urls: ["url7"], ids: [""] }],
    map = new Map,
    result = [],
    fn = a => {
        if (map.has(a.keyword)) {
            map.get(a.keyword).urls.unshift(...a.urls);
            return;
        }
        map.set(a.keyword, a);
        result.push(a);
    };

[array1, array2].forEach(a => a.forEach(fn));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You can get rid of the extra variable/init `result` with a small edit to `fn` to use in a reduce

Comment: Im always surprised how people depend their vote on wether a snippet was added or not ;)

Comment: @Jonasw, it's part of the gamification. and, of course, to check the result.

Comment: Nice job! This is one of the cleanest answers I've seen in a long time. I generally forget that Map is a built-in object.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer doing this with a Map instead of reduce:

```
 const result = [], hash = new Map();

 arr1.concat(arr2).forEach( obj => {
   if( hash.has( obj.keyword ) ){
    hash.get( obj.keyword ).urls.push(...obj.urls);
   }else{
    hash.set( obj.keyword, obj);
    result.push( obj );
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the `urls` property out of the object before you assign to a new object, then add it back if it doesn't exist, or `unshift` into the existing array, if it does exist

```js
var arr1 = [{
  "keyword": "name",
  "score": 0.8992112752974006,
  "urls": ["url1"],
  "ids": ["5748bf9ab58adb2f614da195"]
}, {
  "keyword": "name1",
  "score": 0.39953909596222775,
  "urls": ["url2"],
  "ids": ["5743260055f979a31fa98971"]
}, {
  "keyword": "name3",
  "score": 0.4960953181766197,
  "urls": ["url4"],
  "ids": ["58c04cd5208b4945c3920cad"]
}, {
  "keyword": "name4",
  "score": 0.3337163443410707,
  "urls": ["url5"],
  "ids": ["573628c38e32eeb039377f7e"]
}];

var arr2 = [{
  "keyword": "name",
  "score": 0.8992112752974006,
  "urls": ["url6"],
  "ids": [""]
}, {
  "keyword": "name1",
  "score": 0.39953909596222775,
  "urls": ["url7"],
  "ids": [""]
}]
var a3 = arr1.concat(arr2).reduce((acc, x) => {
  let urls = x.urls; // store temporarily
  delete x.urls;     // delete before merging, to not overwrite

  acc[x.keyword] = Object.assign(acc[x.keyword] || {}, x);
  'urls' in acc[x.keyword] ? [].unshift.apply(acc[x.keyword].urls, urls) : acc[x.keyword].urls = urls;
  // ^      if exists                  unshift                                 or just add
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(a3);
```

Answer (score 0):

For no side effects on `arr1` or `arr2` you'll also need some kind of clone.

```
const a3 = ((a1, a2) => {
    const copy = item => {
        return {
            keyword: item.keyword,
            score: item.score,
            urls: item.urls.slice(),
            ids: item.ids.slice()
        };
    };

    a1 = a1.map(copy);

    const dictionary = a1.reduce((acc, item) => {
        acc[item.keyword] = item;
        return acc;
    }, {});

    a2.forEach(item => {
        if (dictionary[item.keyword]) {
            dictionary[item.keyword].urls = item.urls.concat(dictionary[item.keyword].urls);
        } else {
            const clone = copy(item);
            dictionary[clone.keyword] = clone;
            a1.push(clone);
        }
    });
    return a1;
})(arr1, arr2);
```

I wrote this using arrows as function shorthand/`const`, but the rest is ES5

Answer (score 0):

I used a spread operator to merge the arrays but `unshift()` would work just as well.

```js
function mergeObjects(arrayA, arrayB) {
  var
    // Take all items in arrayA and place them in the result.
    result = arrayA.slice(0);
  // Iterate over all items in array B  
  arrayB.forEach(item => {
    var 
      // Check if there is an item in the result with the same keyword.
      resultItem = result.find(itemA => itemA.keyword === item.keyword);
    // When the keyword isn't yet in the result...
    if (resultItem === null) {
      // ... add it to the result
      result.push(item);
    } else {
      // ... or else add the urls from the current item to the urls of the result.
      resultItem.urls = [...item.urls, ...resultItem.urls];
    }
  });
  
  // Return the result array.
  return result;
}

var arr1 = [{
  "keyword": "name",
  "score": 0.8992112752974006,
  "urls": ["url1"],
  "ids": ["5748bf9ab58adb2f614da195"]
}, {
  "keyword": "name1",
  "score": 0.39953909596222775,
  "urls": ["url2"],
  "ids": ["5743260055f979a31fa98971"]
}, {
  "keyword": "name3",
  "score": 0.4960953181766197,
  "urls": ["url4"],
  "ids": ["58c04cd5208b4945c3920cad"]
}, {
  "keyword": "name4",
  "score": 0.3337163443410707,
  "urls": ["url5"],
  "ids": ["573628c38e32eeb039377f7e"]
}];

var arr2 = [{
  "keyword": "name",
  "score": 0.8992112752974006,
  "urls": ["url6"],
  "ids": [""]
}, {
  "keyword": "name1",
  "score": 0.39953909596222775,
  "urls": ["url7"],
  "ids": [""]
}];

console.log(mergeObjects(arr1, arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

ES5 optimized approach (**without unnecessary iterations**, just "*low-level*" processing):

```js
var arr1 = [{ keyword: "name", score: 0.8992112752974006, urls: ["url1"], ids: ["5748bf9ab58adb2f614da195"] }, { keyword: "name1", score: 0.39953909596222775, urls: ["url2"], ids: ["5743260055f979a31fa98971"] }, { keyword: "name3", score: 0.4960953181766197, urls: ["url4"], ids: ["58c04cd5208b4945c3920cad"] }, { keyword: "name4", score: 0.3337163443410707, urls: ["url5"], ids: ["573628c38e32eeb039377f7e"] }],
    arr2 = [{ keyword: "name", score: 0.8992112752974006, urls: ["url6"], ids: [""] }, { keyword: "name1", score: 0.39953909596222775, urls: ["url7"], ids: [""] }],        
    len1 = arr1.length, c = 0, k = -1;
    
while (c < len1 && (l = arr2.length)) {
    for (i=0; i<l; i++) {
        if (arr1[c].keyword == arr2[i].keyword) {
     arr1[c].urls.unshift(arr2[i].urls[0]);
     k = i;
     break;
 }
    }
    if (k >=0) {
        arr2.splice(k, 1);
        k = -1;
    }
    c++;
}

console.log(arr1);
```

---

***Performance*** comparison results (https://jsperf.com/map-vs-reduce-vs-while-loop):

[image]